# Using GET and Post method in the same page

Tags: php, html

As you can see I get the id from get method, the problem is when I using the `$id` to update the record it doesnt work but if I replace the `$id` with a number it works just fine, for example (`$query = "UPDATE article SET title='$title_up', utitle='$utitle_up', text='$text_up', image='$image_up' WHERE id=2";`)

PHP code:

```
$id = $_GET['id'];

$sql="SELECT * FROM article WHERE id = '$id'";
        
$result=mysqli_query($conn,$sql);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    $image = $row['image'];
    $title = $row['title'];
    $utitle = $row['utitle'];
    $text = $row['text'];
}

if(isset($_POST['update'])){

    $title_up = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_REQUEST['title']);
    $utitle_up = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_REQUEST['utitle']);
    $image_up = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_REQUEST['image']);
    $text_up = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_REQUEST['text']);
    
    
    $query = "UPDATE article SET title='$title_up', utitle='$utitle_up', text='$text_up', image='$image_up' WHERE id='$id'";
    
    mysqli_query($conn, $query);

    if ($conn->query($query) === TRUE) {
        echo "Record updated successfully";
    } else {
        echo "Error updating record: " . $conn->error;
    }
}
```

HTML form code:

```
<form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>" method="POST">
    <label for='title'>Title: </label> <br>
    <input type='text' id='title' name='title' value="<?php echo$title;?>"/> <br>
            
    <label for='utitle'>UTitle: </label> <br>
    <input type='text' id='utitle' name='utitle' value="<?php echo$utitle;?>"/> <br>
                 
    <label for='text'>Text: </label> <br>
                
    <input type='text' id='text' name='text' value="<?php echo$text;?>"/> <br>
                
    <input type='text' id='image' name='image' value="<?php echo$image;?>" /> <br>
                
    <input type="submit" name="update" value="Update"  />
            
</form>
```

Comment: Your code is open to SQL injection attacks! Please, read [How to prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60496).

Comment: Try dumping `$_GET`. Does an `id` key even exist?

Comment: **Warning!!!** Your code is open for [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection), please use [prepared statements](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) preferably with [PDO](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) or [mysqli](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace this line :

```
<form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>" method="POST">
```

By this :

```
<form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]);?>" method="POST">
```

**EDIT** :

```
$_SERVER["PHP_SELF"] // return just file
$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"] // return file and GET parameters
```